# How to create a drop down menu by retrieving items in the 'itemname' column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a sales page...My question is,
how do i create a drop down menu in the item name row of `sold.php` so that other fields (item price, 
item code, itemtype) get filled automatically from data the database?..Thank you in advance.

Here's the products table named `manuf`

```
| id | itemname | itemcode |itemtype|
|:---|---------:|:--------:|        |
| 1  |stuff     | 457      | kl45   |
| 2  |stuff2    | 745      | l152   |
```

This is the page for sale  `sold.php`

```
 <?php require_once('../Connections/bidco.php'); ?>

    <?php
    mysql_select_db($database_bidco, $bidco);
    $query_rsSaletype = "SELECT * FROM saletype ORDER BY type ASC";
    $rsSaletype = mysql_query($query_rsSaletype, $bidco) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsSaletype = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSaletype);
    $totalRows_rsSaletype = mysql_num_rows($rsSaletype);

    mysql_select_db($database_bidco, $bidco);
    $query_rsCustomercategory = "SELECT * FROM buyertype ORDER BY type ASC";
    $rsCustomercategory = mysql_query($query_rsCustomercategory, $bidco) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsCustomercategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomercategory);
    $totalRows_rsCustomercategory = mysql_num_rows($rsCustomercategory);

    mysql_select_db('invmgt', mysql_connect('localhost','root','')) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <?php
        //Start session
        session_start();    
        //Unset the variables stored in session
        unset($_SESSION['SESS_ID']);
        unset($_SESSION['SESS_Username']);
        unset($_SESSION['SESS_Name']);
    ?>
    <?php
    if (isset ($_POST ['Submit']))
    {
    $da=date("Y-m-d");
    $itemname=$_POST['itemname'];
    $itemcode=$_POST['itemcode'];
    $itemtype=$_POST['itemtype'];
    $price=$_POST['unitprice'];
    $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
    $ttype=$_POST['select2'];
    $ccat=$_POST['select'];
    $idate=date("Y-m-d");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO sold_goods (itemname, itemcode, itemtype, unitprice, quantity, transactiontype, customercategory, 

Date) VALUES ('$itemname', '$itemcode', '$itemtype', '$unitprice', '$quantity', '$ttype', '$ccat', '$idate')");

    mysql_query("UPDATE manuf SET qtyleft = qtyleft - $quantity where
     itemcode = '$itemcode'" );

    header("location:sold.php");
     }                      

     ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-

transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="711" height="27" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="216"><a href="../manufactured_goods/manuf.php">Manufactured Goods</a> </td>
        <td width="152"><a href="sold.php">Sold Goods</a> </td>
        <td width="148"><a href="../client_details/client.php">Client Details </a></td>
        <td width="167"><a href="../users_accounts/users.php">User Accounts </a></td>
        <td width="167"><a href="../login/menu.php">Home </a></td>
        <td width="167"><div align="right"><a href="../login/logout.php">Logout </a></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <form id="form9" name="form9" method="POST" action="">
      <table width="828" height="572" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td height="55" colspan="3"><div align="center"><strong>SOLD GOODS </strong></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="33" colspan="2">User</td>
          <td height="33"><?php date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi'); echo "Time " . date("h:i:sa");
    ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="14">Customer code
            <div align="center"></div></td>
          <td height="14">Customer category        
            <select name="select2">
              <?php
    do {  
    ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_rsCustomercategory['type']?>"><?php echo $row_rsCustomercategory['type']?></option>
              <?php
    } while ($row_rsCustomercategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomercategory));
      $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCustomercategory);
      if($rows > 0) {
          mysql_data_seek($rsCustomercategory, 0);
          $row_rsCustomercategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomercategory);
      }
    ?>
            </select></td>
          <td height="14"><?php echo "Date of Transaction " . date("Y/m/d")?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="15">&nbsp;</td>
          <td height="15">&nbsp;</td>
          <td height="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="32" colspan="2"><div align="center"><strong>ITEM DETAILS </strong></div></td>
          <td width="258" rowspan="3"><div align="center"></div>
              <div align="center"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="227" height="23"><div align="right">Item name </div></td>
          <td width="321"><input name="itemname" type="text" id=itemname /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right">Item code </div></td>
          <td><input name="itemcode" type="text" id="itemcode" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right">Item type </div></td>
          <td><input name="itemtype" type="text" id="itemtype" /></td>
          <td rowspan="3"><div align="center"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="23"><div align="right">Unit price </div></td>
          <td><input name="unitprice" type="text" id=price /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="32"><div align="right">Quantity </div></td>
          <td><input name="quantity" type="text" id=qty /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="42" colspan="2"><div align="center"><strong>SALES</strong></div></td>
          <td><div align="center"></div>
              <div align="center"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right">Gross</div></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><div align="center"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right">Type of sale </div></td>
          <td><select name="select">
            <?php
    do {  
    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_rsSaletype['type']?>"><?php echo $row_rsSaletype['type']?></option>
            <?php
    } while ($row_rsSaletype = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSaletype));
      $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsSaletype);
      if($rows > 0) {
          mysql_data_seek($rsSaletype, 0);
          $row_rsSaletype = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSaletype);
      }
    ?>
          </select></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="28" colspan="2"><div align="center"><strong>DEDUCTIONS</strong></div></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="36"><div align="right">Discount</div></td>
          <td height="36">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="ADD NEW" />
          </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="36"><div align="right">V.A.T</div></td>
          <td height="36">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="36"><div align="right">Net</div></td>
          <td height="36">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2"><div align="center">
              <input type="reset" name="Submit5" value="CANCEL" />
          </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="30" colspan="2"><div align="center">
            <label><strong>CALCULATE</strong></label>
          </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </form>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($rsSaletype);

    mysql_free_result($rsCustomercategory);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ajax for this 
first add id for dropdow as dropdown
In Ajax

```js
$('#dropdown').change(function())
{

var id=$('#dropdown').val();
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "id="+id ,
                success: function(html){
                    $("table").append(html);
                }
            });
});
```

in ajax.php file you should retrieve values from id

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$qu="select * from goods where id='$id'";
$s=mysql_query($q);
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($s))
{
 echo "<tr><td>".$r['goodname']."</td>"<td>".$r['price']."</td>"<td>".$r['date']."</td></tr>"


}

}

 ?>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ajax, is there a way to implement it in php?

Answer (score 0):

Bascially in a nutshell you are going to want to query your data base and then run a while loop through each row of the database results like

```
echo '<select>';
$row = mysqli->fetch_row()
while($row != null)
   echo '<option value="'$row[0]'">$row[0] (for column 1 of that row) </select>';
   $row = mysqli->fetch_row();
}
echo '</select>';
```

etc.. when you echo out html it will be placed on the page where you coded it, by doing it this way you can insert database values on load.

Comment: the code does not retrieve anything from the database

Comment: your question says you need to pull from the database. My example does that, not exactly how you need to, but the theory is there. Tweak it to suit your needs.